# Refresh Google OAuth2 Token - returned token is null in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code to renew a Google Token

```
function refreshOAuthToken(ClientId, ClientSecret, RefreshToken, CallbackUri)
{
    var client;

    try {
        var tokenProvider = new GoogleTokenProvider({
            refresh_token: RefreshToken,
            client_id: ClientId,
            client_secret: ClientSecret
        });

        console.log(' **** Token Data *****');

        console.log('Refresh Token : ' + RefreshToken);
        console.log('Client Id :     ' + ClientId);
        console.log('Client Secret : ' + ClientSecret);

        tokenProvider.getToken(function (err, token) {
            if (err || !token) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Unable to refresh OAuth Token " + err);
                }
                else {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Token returned Error ' + err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Token returned was empty ');
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("Successfully refreshed token ");
                console.log("Token " + token.access_token);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Big Error Refreshing Token " + e.message);
    }
}
```

But the token returned is null, as is the err object - so I am not getting back a valid (refreshed) token and nor am I getting an error back to find out what is wrong.

I have used the tokens I have to retrieve data so am pretty certain they are valid.

This is using the refresh-token node package and GoogleTokenProvider is initialised by the the following line.

```
var GoogleTokenProvider = require('refresh-token').GoogleTokenProvider;
```

see https://www.npmjs.org/package/refresh-token

Anyone see why the Token is null?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without more information, there's not much to do here.  Show us what library you're using, for starters.

Comment: Added information about Library, anything else you need - not sure what else I can give.

Comment: Well, it appears by looking through the source, an object is not returned, but the token itself.  Please try `console.log("Token " + token);`

Comment: Just tried and for some reason it is working now - I'm sure last night  I tried and it was not working and now it does. Thanks anyway.